# No matter what I get a error in AWS CLI Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I keep getting the same error even though I believe my command is correct.
Here is my command

```
$ aws lambda create-function \
    --function-name test-function \
    --runtime python3.6.9 \
    --zip-file fileb:///home/USERNAME/awsFolder/test-lambda.zip \
    --handler test-lambda.my-handler \
    --role are:blah:blah:blah
```

I keep getting

> --zip-file must be a zip file with the fileb:// prefix.
>
> Example usage:  --zip-file fileb://path/to/file.zip

I have tried absolute path (with '///' as well as '//' and even '/') i have been in the working directory and just used the file name.

what am i doing wrong!?

Comment: Note that `python3.6.9` is not a valid Lambda runtime.

Comment: yes, thanks. i have it as python3.6 now. same issue

Comment: 1. You need to use it similarly as defined in example (i.e. no need to add 666 '/' symbols). 2. Is test-lambda.zip correct ZIP archive with Lambda function?

Comment: thanks for the comment, yes, it turned out I incorrectly zipped the file! i was using `base64` command.  Using `zip` command solved my issue.